# Sequentially add one second to date/time field of MySQL cell with conditions

Tags: mysql, wordpress

It seems to be working fine, but I just want to be sure this query does what expected as I am an absolute noob in MySQL and want to avoid any damage to my database.

Here is what I am looking for:

The query will search **wp_posts** table for rows containing ***attachment*** or ***page*** in *post_type* field, then sort all found rows in ascending order by *post_title* field and finally make any changes.

For example

```
---------------------------------------------
post_date           | post_type  | post_title
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:00 | page       | C
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:01 | attachment | A
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:02 | attachment | E
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:03 | other      | D
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:04 | page       | B
---------------------------------------------
```

should become

```
---------------------------------------------
post_date           | post_type  | post_title
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:02 | page       | C
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:00 | attachment | A
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:03 | attachment | E
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:03 | other      | D
---------------------------------------------
2016-04-02 15:00:01 | page       | B
---------------------------------------------
```

Time for post_title D have been ignored because it is of non compliant post_type, all other post_titles got their new time entry according to their ascended alphabetical order.

Is this query correct for doing this?

```
set @mytime_post_date = -1;
update wp_posts set post_date = cast('2016-04-02 15:00:00' AS DATETIME) + interval (@mytime_post_date := @mytime_post_date + 1) second WHERE (post_type='attachment' OR post_type='page') ORDER BY post_title ASC;
```

And thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar for your help with the initial query. )

Comment: if it is working fine. So it is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct. Good luck researching! )